# Get checkbox value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I alert this, and alert 'undefined':

```
alert($("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val());
```

But when I try this, why alert 'no':

```
if($("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == 'undefined')
    alert('yes')
else
    alert('no')
```

That fix my problem:

```
if(typeof $("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == 'undefined')
    alert('yes')
else
    alert('no')
```

Comment: please show us your code in a fiddle

Comment: Change it to `if(typeof $("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == 'undefined')` - what happens now?

Comment: try this :) some html could help btw :)
$("input[name='searchManagers']").is( ':checked' );

Comment: Try this on:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Answer (score 3):

The second one you are comparing to a string instead of the `undefined` type.

Try this:

```
if($("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == undefined)
```

or:

```
if(typeof $("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$("input[name='searchManagers']").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because undefined != 'undefined'
If you were to modify your code

```
  if($("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == undefined)
    alert('yes')
  else
    alert('no')
```

Then it should work

Answer (score 1):

change 'undefined' to undefined without quotes

```
if($("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val() == undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure set the id and name property in check box. And try below the code.

```
if(!$("input[name='searchManagers']:checked").val()){
    alert('Plase select the searchManagers');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make some changes and find the output.

```
  if ($("input[name='searchManagers']").is(':checked'))
  alert('yes');
  else
  alert('no');
```